# How to use IMAGE function from both Dialogflow and Actions-on-Google libraries

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using the Fulfillment inline editor. My agent is using functions from both Dialogflow and Actions-on-Google. I have already used succesfull Image functions from Dialogflow, but I also need to use the image of the Action-on-Google library for another. How to do this?

```
    // DialogFlow functions
const { WebhookClient, Card, Image, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
// https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs
const {dialogflow, Suggestions, BasicCard, MediaObject, SimpleResponse, Table, Button, List} = require('actions-on-google');
```

The most simple solution would be to add the IMAGE function to the Actions-on-Google functions:

```
const {dialogflow, [...], Image, List} = require('actions-on-google');
```

But unfortunately this of course not possible due to ambiguity. How to solve this?

Comment: Usually one uses either the dialogflow-fulfillment or the actions-on-google client library, but not both. What's the use case that requires both client libraries?

Comment: Hi @lukedavis, I'm building an app whats need to deployed to at least 3 platforms, Google Assistant, Web iframe, and slack. There are some problems in using images  on Actions-on-Google (only 2 in one answer allowed) and I would like to make use of special Actions-on-Google capabilities. That's why I need both.